# TypeError: /Users/ac/Downloads/BeFound/views/profile.ejs:91

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Got this error when I click on a page in my nodejs app and im not sure what's wrong with it

```
TypeError: /Users/ac/Downloads/BeFound/views/profile.ejs:91
    89|                       
    90|                       <div>
 >> 91|                         <%- include('profilePartials/options') %>
    92|                       </div>
    93| 
    94|                      

/Users/ac/Downloads/BeFound/views/profilePartials/options.ejs:5
    3|         <div>
    4|    <div  id="opt-newsfeed">
 >> 5|     <%- include('newsfeed') %> 
    6|    </div>
    7|    <div id="opt-profile">
    8|     <%- include('detailedProfile') %> 

/Users/ac/Downloads/BeFound/views/profilePartials/newsfeed.ejs:268
    266|                                   
    267| 
 >> 268|                                     <img class="commentimg" src="<%= com.createdBy.displayPicture.image %>" alt="altt"
    269|                                     style="border-radius: 50%" />
    270|                                   <% } %>
    271| 

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')
    at eval ("/Users/ac/Downloads/BeFound/views/profilePartials/newsfeed.ejs":174:55)
    at Proxy.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval ("/Users/ac/Downloads/BeFound/views/profilePartials/newsfeed.ejs":141:22)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval ("/Users/ac/Downloads/BeFound/views/profilePartials/newsfeed.ejs":15:14)
    at newsfeed
```

(/Users/ac/Downloads/BeFound/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:692:17)
at include
(/Users/ac/Downloads/BeFound/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:690:39)
at eval
("/Users/ac/Downloads/BeFound/views/profilePartials/options.ejs":12:17)
at options
(/Users/ac/Downloads/BeFound/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:692:17)
at include
(/Users/ac/Downloads/BeFound/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:690:39)

Comment: It means that `com.createdBy.displayPicture` is `undefined`

Comment: Any idea how I can fix that

Comment: Your ejs template gets rendered by a call to `res.render("profile", data);`. You need to make sure that `data` contains the correct data. Open the newsfeed.ejs template and look at the surrounding lines. Chances are it's a loop and `com` is an array item. Each array item must have `{ createdBy: { displayPicture: { image: "some_url_here" }}}` for the template code to work as expected. Is this code somebody else wrote?

Comment: Also keep in mind that stackoverflow is not a free debugging service (even though lots of people including high rep users seem to think that). If this isn't your code, you need to ask the person who wrote it to fix it. If this is your code, you need to understand what's happening and try to fix it.